# How do you set the CSS styles of child elements from within the parent's style attribute?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

Example:

```
<div style="SET IMAGE ATTRIBUTES HERE!">
    <img src="http://somesite.com/someimg.jpg"><br />
    <img src="http://someothersite.com/someotherimg.jpg"><br />
    ...
</div>
```

Due to the structure of my dynamic ASP.NET code generation, I would prefer to avoid using pre-defined CSS classes. These attributes will vary from one webcontrol to another, and cannot be set globally in the `<head>` or `<body>` sections. For example, I might have two of my webcontrols on a single page, each with different CSS attributes set for all of their child-images.

As a last resort, I can piece together a dynamic CSS class generator for these controls - but that would be a giant pain, with really sloppy results. Namely, each webcontrol would generate their own CSS class, write it in the `head` or `body` sections somehow, all while making sure that multiple webcontrols aren't using the same name for their CSS classes. Like I said, a giant sloppy mess - hence I'd love to be able to cram all this information into the attribute tags for the individual controls, so they don't step on each-other's toes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could you make something like this:

```
 <div id="yourcontrol_1">
    <img src="/some/image.jpg">
 </div>
```

and then define the styles in a stylesheet - not inline:

```
#yourcontrol_1 img {
    border: 20px double red;
}
```

That way, whatever you specify only applies to the `img` tags that are children of id `yourcontrol_1`.

This level of control is not possible with inline styles, IIRC.

If you have no way of determining the classname/id beforehand, you could still generate them, and embed the styles using the `style` tag. As you say: not pretty, but it would work.

```
<html>
  <head>
     <style>
       #generated_identifier_0xcafe img {
          padding: 200em;
       }
       #generated_identifier_0xbeef img {
          background-color: green;
       }
     </style>
   </head>
   <body>
     <div id="generated_identifier_0xcafe">
         <img src="someimage.png">
     </div>
   <!-- etc... -->
```

Comment: All said, I think this is the best solution, since the other workarounds are buggy or place restrictions on the parent. This will likely also provide the best overall performance.

Comment: Best answer for setting children attributes.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is you can't.

The value of a style element is exactly equivalent to a ruleset with a selector that matches the element (except with higher specificity).

The only way for a value of a property there to be assigned to an element inside is if that element has the rule `whatever-property-it-is: inherit` (which is buggy in older versions of IE).

Comment: Yeah, that would be a loophole in this case. But the options are very limited (design wise) since you'll be applying the same styles to the parent and child elements.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need classes to do what you wish, simply put the `style` attributes on the images themselves.

```
<div>
    <img src="http://somesite.com/someimg.jpg" style="image styles here!"><br />
    <img src="http://someothersite.com/someotherimg.jpg" style="image styles here!"><br />
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, good point. Can get ridiculously repetitive with a large number of style rules though.

Comment: @Piskvor Definitely so, I would never advise having to do this if a large number of images had the same details, a class would be much better.  However the poster states that he needs to avoid them, so this is the solution.  Perfectly acceptable if there is no or little repetition.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible. With inline CSS you can only set styles for the current element.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 has introduced an experimental `scoped` attribute for the style tag that will do exactly what you want:

```
<div>
   <style scoped>img { border: 20px double red; }</style>
   <!-- style applies to this div and its children only -->
```

It's marked as "not ready for production code", but it worked in Firefox, Chrome, and Edge in a simple test I just did. [HTML Doctor](http://html5doctor.com/the-scoped-attribute/) lists several valid use cases, such as themed plugins and user-defined styles on wiki code.